# Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() not working and giving /storage

Tags: android, path, storage, external, android-sdcard

My code

```
myDb = openOrCreateDatabase("/sdcard/FashionGirl/ImagesDB.db", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
myDb = openOrCreateDatabase(dbPath, Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
```

worked perfectly, but was giving warning `Do not hardcode "/sdcard/"; use Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() instead`

So I tried,

```
String dbPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "FashionGirl/ImagesDB.db";
myDb = openOrCreateDatabase(dbPath, Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
```

But strangely, its not working, where Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() has value `/storage`

So its giving error,

```
12-17 19:32:02.230: E/SqliteDatabaseCpp(15620): sqlite3_open_v2("/storageFashionGirl/ImagesDB.db", &handle, 6, NULL) failed
12-17 19:32:02.230: E/SQLiteDatabase(15620): Failed to open the database. closing it.
12-17 19:32:02.230: E/SQLiteDatabase(15620): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unable to open database file
12-17 19:32:02.230: E/SQLiteDatabase(15620):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.dbopen(Native Method)
12-17 19:32:02.230: E/SQLiteDatabase(15620):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:983)
12-17 19:32:02.230: E/SQLiteDatabase(15620):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:956)
12-17 19:32:02.230: E/SQLiteDatabase(15620):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:932)
```

So why something recommended by Android is not working, what should I do?

Comment: "/storageFashionGirl/" maybe you need to add a "/" like this:
String dbPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + "FashionGirl/ImagesDB.db";

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
String dbPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "FashionGirl/ImagesDB.db";
myDb = openOrCreateDatabase(dbPath, Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
```

Please do not use concatenation for constructing file paths. Try:

```
File dbPath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "FashionGirl/ImagesDB.db");
myDb = openOrCreateDatabase(dbPath.getAbsolutePath(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
```

> But strangely, its not working, where Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() has value /storage

That is because `/sdcard` has been deprecated for nearly three years.

Comment: @WhyandHow: That has been considered poor form in Java for 10-15 years. Using the `File` constructor not only protects you from missing-path-separator errors like you had, but also deals with other platform specifics (e.g., `/` vs. `\` on Windows). That latter feature is perhaps not as important for an Android-only app, but using the `File` constructor instead of concatenation is a good habit in general.

Answer (score 2):

Add **/** before Fashiongirl

```
String dbPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/FashionGirl/ImagesDB.db";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
List<Employee> employees = null;
try {
    XMLPullParserHandler parser = new XMLPullParserHandler();

    File f = new File("/mnt/extsd/kmls/mykml.kml");

    InputStream is = new FileInputStream(f);

            employees = parser.parse(is);

       ArrayAdapter<Employee> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Employee>     

this,R.layout.list_item, employees);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

Note : "/mnt/extsd/kmls/mykml.kml" this is the complete path to reach my kml fiel.
   for this first you need to open your sdcard in your device then you find the path   
then the path need to insert into your app.

thanks
```